# Can't connect to SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have the following code, just to test connection:

```
public void Test()
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=/Application/Database.sdf;");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        label1.text = "Connection!";
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        label1.text = "No connection!";
    }
}
```

When trying to connect to this database, the application throws an exception at `conn.Open()` saying

> SqlCeException was unhandled

and nothing more. The exception message is blank, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what went wrong.

The database file is there, and the application returns true with

```
File.Exist(@"/Application/Database.sdf");
```

so it does have access to the file.

**I'm probably doing something really wrong here, can anyone help me out with this?**

I'm using Compact Framework 2.0 on Windows CE 5, and the application in question is an existing one. I'm trying to add a database to it so I can load large amounts of data much more easier.

Comment: Start by implementing proper error handling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ms174079(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: If you enter the full path does it work? Also, should your `/` be `\\`?

Comment: I would also just double-check you can connect to it in SSMS (or your favourite database management tool) fine.

Comment: @ErikEJ I know, this is just something I wrote real quick - It's not for production purposes.

Comment: @Belogix This is the full path, CE has those two switched around for some reason.

Comment: @Arran I can access the database fine using VS2008 if that makes any importance

Comment: But proper error handling might give you a hint to what the error is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Erik is saying is change your code to this:

```
public void Test()
{
  SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=/Application/Database.sdf;");
  try
  {
    conn.Open();
    label1.text = "Connection!";
  }
  catch (SqlCeException ee)  // <- Notice the use of SqlCeException to read your errors
  {
    SqlCeErrorCollection errorCollection = ee.Errors;

    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
    Exception inner = ee.InnerException;

    if (null != inner) 
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Inner Exception: " + inner.ToString());
    }
    // Enumerate the errors to a message box.
    foreach (SqlCeError err in errorCollection) 
    {
      bld.Append("\n Error Code: " + err.HResult.ToString("X")); 
      bld.Append("\n Message   : " + err.Message);
      bld.Append("\n Minor Err.: " + err.NativeError);
      bld.Append("\n Source    : " + err.Source);

      // Enumerate each numeric parameter for the error.
      foreach (int numPar in err.NumericErrorParameters) 
      {
        if (0 != numPar) bld.Append("\n Num. Par. : " + numPar);
      }

      // Enumerate each string parameter for the error.
      foreach (string errPar in err.ErrorParameters) 
      {
        if (String.Empty != errPar) bld.Append("\n Err. Par. : " + errPar);
      }

    }
    label1.text = bld.ToString();
    bld.Remove(0, bld.Length);
  }
}
```

The generic `Exception` you are catching right now can not give you the details of the `SqlCeException`.